# Putting code for vertx service proxy into docker

Tags: docker, proxy, vert.x, vertx-verticle

I am going to be calling an ESB, so I want to make a service proxy for that code.

Since it is going to be common to several verticles, as the code is largely consistent between each ESB call, I will create other service proxies that are specific.

So, to look up open orders for a user, the OrderVerticle will put a request on the event bus, and the OpenOrderService will then put in the request for the ESBService.

So, my problem is I have everything dockerized, so each Verticle is in its own container.  How do I dockerize the eventbus code?  Should I just have one docker container with all the projects that are for the event bus?

That seems to be a bad idea, so what is the correct way to handle this?

Another thought was to put all of the service proxy projects for each verticle into the docker container for that verticle but that also seems wrong.

So, trying to understand the correct way to do this, as the simple way, but wrong, is to create new Verticles instead of a serviceproxy and then just make `GRPC` or `RPC` calls from the `OrderVerticle` to `OpenOrderVerticle` and from there to `ESBVerticle`.

Answer (score 0):

Vert.x can be started in clustered mode. In this case, the EventBus will span multiple nodes (running or not in a container).

So you could deploy verticles A and B on node 1; C, D and E one node 2. Just as if they were all deployed on the same JVM.

Here's the list of supported cluster managers: http://vertx.io/docs/#clustering

Comment: So would I put my service proxies in the docker container with each verticle that is using them? Thanks

Comment: On each client node, you need to make the client side of the service available on the classpath.